# How to use regular expressions to convert numbers to double quoted string of numbers?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace all the numbers with double quoted numbers. Below is my String which I have in notepad++ -

```
test1:{0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:1, 5:2, 6:3, 7:4, 8:1, 9:2, 10:3, 11:4, 12:1, 13:2, 14:3, 15:4, 17:2, 16:1}
test2:{0:2, 1:3, 2:4, 3:1, 4:3, 5:4, 6:1, 7:2, 8:4, 9:1, 10:2, 11:3, 12:2, 13:3, 14:4, 15:1, 17:4, 16:3}
```

Is there any way by using regular expressions, I can replace all the numbers with a double quoted string of numbers -

Meaning something like this -

```
0 will become "0"
1 will become "1"
```

and same thing with other numbers..

Comment: substitute `(\d)` with `"$1"`? Or something to that effect anyway.

Comment: Why not Google it? You get http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions#Substitutions. Read it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and use :-

Find What : `(\d+):(\d+)`

Replace with : `"\1":"\2"`

and click Replace all.

Make sure you have selected "Regular Expression" checkobox for Search Mode